# Download an embed swf object from a webpage to server

Tags: php, html, object, embed, flashvars

I know how to cache images from webpages, and save them.

But i wanna know how download a **"application/x-shockwave-flash"** file from a webpage with the element below :

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/media/player/flvplayer.swf" width="550" height="450" style="undefined" id="single" name="single" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" menu="false" flashvars="file=/files/fa/news/91/11/12/143130_319.flv&amp;width=550&amp;height=450">
```

OR think it as i want to extract the link of file.

From what i see above, the link to file is :

`http://domain.com/files/fa/news/91/11/12/143130_319.flv`

How to extract it ? ( suppose that some **flashvars** attributes are not exactly as above )

*Or any other idea would be appreciated.*

Comment: Use an online extractor.

Comment: @David that's about coding, not using online tools. tnx